# lscpu and /proc/cpuinfo shows constant cpu frequency

Tags: 16.04, grub2, kernel, cpu

However, such script

```
 watch -n 1 'for i in $(seq 0 7); do cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq; done;'
```

shows that turboboost is working and everything fine.

**The strangest thing is that BIOS shows constant cpu frequency too !!! (3400Mhz)**

Setup:

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

4.13.0-36-generic

i7-6700

**UPDATE**

After update to the latest version of a BIOS (2018) nothing has changed.

**UPDATE**

The same thing is happens on my laptop with identical setup except CPU - 7820HQ.

Comment: Check the output of the command `sudo i7z` - You would probably need to install it first `sudo apt install i7z`. This works best with Intel CPUs.